# Filtering string/float/integer values in pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, integer

How can I filter only string values/ integer/ float values in one column  (`SIC`) in a pandas data frame like below?

```
                         SIC
1                      246804
2                      135272
3                      898.01
4                     3453.33
5                       shine  
6                        add
7                         522
8                         Nan
9                      string
10                      29.11
11                        20
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the outputs from `pd.to_numeric` and boolean indexing.

To get only the strings use:

```
df[pd.to_numeric(df.SIC, errors='coerce').isnull()]
```

Output:

```
      SIC
5   shine
6     add
8     Nan
9  string
```

To get only the numbers use:

```
df[pd.to_numeric(df.SIC, errors='coerce').notnull()]
```

Output:

```
        SIC
1    246804
2    135272
3    898.01
4   3453.33
7       522
10    29.11
11       20
```

Comment: Note that `to_numeric` considers hex literals (0xFF) non-numeric, which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `apply()` method along with the `isinstance()` function. Can replace `str` with `int`, `float`, etc:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,4.5,np.NAN,'asdf',5,'string'],columns=['SIC'])
print(df)
      SIC
0       1
1       2
2     4.5
3     NaN
4    asdf
5       5
6  string

print(df[df['SIC'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x,str))])
      SIC
4    asdf
6  string
```