# Filter column by float value in pandas dataframe, and fill-forward

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

```
    difer   length     
0   0.11          4
1   NaN           6
2   01_00532      54
3   NaN           32
4   NaN           12 
5   0.10          12
6   Nan           123
```

I want to replace in the `difer` column all other values with the float values. So change all values to 0.11 till the next float value (0.10), then repeat that with 0.10.

```
   difer        length     
0   0.11          4
1   0.11          6
2   0.11          54
3   0.11          32
4   0.11          12 
5   0.10          12
6   0.10          123
```

For the first part (filtering the colum), I found a similar question to
[filter float values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45338209/filtering-string-float-interger-values-in-columns-pandas).

That person recommends using `pd.to_numeric` and boolean indexing
but I don't know why he wrote the column name in this form `df.SIC`. It doesn't work for me:

```
df[pd.to_numeric(df.SIC, errors='coerce').isnull()]
```

For the second part (how to change all values to 0.11 till the next float value (0.10) and repeat it with 0.10), I have no clue.

Comment: That other answer says refer to the column as `SIC` because that's its name! `df.SIC` and `df['SIC']` are two ways of referring to the column, by name. But obviously your column is called `difer` not `SIC`!

Comment: As to *"change all values to 0.11 till the next float value"* that's called *"fill forward"*. See the doc for [`df.fillna(..., method='ffill')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and its synonym [`df.ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pd.to_numeric` on your column, `errors='coerce'` will fill all non numeric values with `NaN` and finally use [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) to forward fill the column.

```
df['difer'] = pd.to_numeric(df['difer'], errors='coerce').ffill()
```

**Output**

```
   difer  length
0   0.11       4
1   0.11       6
2   0.11      54
3   0.11      32
4   0.11      12
5   0.10      12
6   0.10     123
```

NOTE:

There is no difference whether you access a column via `df.difer` or `df['difer']`. This causes a problem only when you have a space in column name. In that case use the later.